# Poisson Ranges for Small Numbers?

Tags: r, poisson-distribution, range

I came across a presentation from a major university on R and Monte Carlo simulations. It mentioned that if you wanted to create ranges for numbers you are going to use in a Poisson distribution, you could use something like:

```
lambda +/- 3 * sqrt(lambda)
```

But it gave the caveat that this would only work for larger numbers (which makes sense). Are there other formulas like this that I can use to create ranges for smaller lambdas (like anywhere from 5 - 15)

Comment: It might help to include the link to the presentation

Comment: The Poisson distribution is not useful with $\lambda$-values that low. With values that low, the negative binomial that converges to the Poisson for larger mean values is used for counting statistics.

Comment: @Carl That's a strange statement.  The Poisson distribution is useful in all sorts of circumstances and is *especially* useful for small $\lambda$.

Comment: @Carl I regularly deal with real data problems quite well-modelled using Poisson distributions where the parameters are substantially less than 1; indeed frequently they're below 0.01. Many of the questions of interest cannot be answered by treating it as binomial (e.g. something more or less akin to "If we have a Poisson process with $\lambda=0.1$ per unit of time and we observe it for 8.5 time units, what's the probability of at least two events?"). The question here about about typical ranges for small values of $\lambda$ seems to make perfect sense to me.

Comment: @DMS please give more context for the thing we're discussing -- what are these calculated ranges being used to do?

Comment: @Glen_b Understood. My prototypical scenario is radioactive decay. Without knowing what the context is, I will take you word for it that the Poisson distribution can be used for $\lambda$'s that are fractional. It is not within the range of my experience, but I cannot deny the plausibility of what you have said. I would, however, request a context from you for when you have results of that type, and how you know they are physical.

Comment: @Carl It happens with radioactive decay: Consider some sample that is generating decay events at the rate of 0.63 decay events per second. What's the probability of getting more than one event in the next 1.5 seconds?

Comment: @Glen_b Offhand wouldn't know. Is that homework to me, or will you complete the example?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the number is, the point is that's a valid question relating to a Poisson model for radioactive decay with non-integer $\lambda$ (and indeed, with $\lambda<1$). Didn't you just suggest that this doesn't happen with radioactive decay applications?

Comment: @Glen_b The problem with whole number results and frequencies of occurrence that are low is that, I think, the Poisson model breaks down. One could show this just by changing time scales on a single data set, and the loss of agreement for small numbers of occurrences for faster (shorter) time intervals. Look at the last figure for [Regression models...](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/seminars/count_presentation/count.htm). If I am reading this correctly, it is a problem. In any case, the quoted "large number" requirement in the Q has no other explanation proposed.

Comment: I don't see the issue -- surely you're not saying "A heterogeneous data set exists with small expected value that a Poisson distribution doesn't fit, therefore the Poisson doesn't work for any application with similarly small mean"? Alternatively, if you aren't saying that's a reason to think that as a general principle "the Poisson model breaks down", what exactly are you saying?

Comment: @Glen_b I don't want to disclose what these numbers are for and I really don't see what impact that has on the question or the ability to answer the question.

Comment: @Carl I think you're adding complexity where none is needed. To my knowledge, there is no "size" limitation on using Poisson. For Poisson, the only requirement is that they need to be singular, independent events. But other than that, it shouldn't matter whether that number is big or small (the number in your sample does count, but thats where limits stop).

Comment: Who would have thought that my little innocuous question on ranges would cause such long discussion!

Comment: @DMS For $\lambda<9$, $\lambda -3 \sqrt{\lambda }<0$, so there is an obvious size limitation.

Comment: @DMS It really does matter what the interval represents. I have a bunch of advice but I can't post it because I have no way to tell if I am even talking about the right kind of interval. [While it's also often very useful to know what the original data are (e.g. it often reveals issues the OP is unaware of), that wasn't what I was asking you for.] If I gave you a way to calculate the interval, *what would that interval be used to do*? Is it an interval for a future value of the process? An interval in order to plot something related to the process? ,,,etc. "Create ranges for numbers" is vague

Comment: @DMS I would like to know what is transpiring physically or failing that, statistically, otherwise, I do not know how to model it. For example, can I assume that a uniform distribution sequence of Dirac $\delta$'s is the data model? I also agree with Glen_b, we need to know what interval you want.

Comment: @DMS The range of a nonzero Poisson distribution is always infinite. If this is not the answer you seek, you are misusing terminology and need to rewrite your question. Do you want quartiles? Confidence intervals? Whatever it is, it is definitely not a range. That is partly why you are not getting a straight answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the cumulative density function of a Poisson distribution $\text{CDF}=\frac{\Gamma(\lfloor k+1\rfloor, \lambda)}{\lfloor k\rfloor !}$, or $e^{-\lambda} \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor k\rfloor} \frac{\lambda^i}{i!}\ $, or $Q(\lfloor k+1\rfloor,\lambda)$
for $k\ge 0$, where $\Gamma(x, y)$ is the upper incomplete gamma function,  $\lfloor k\rfloor$ is the floor function, and $Q$ is the regularized upper incomplete gamma function. Then one can choose $k$-values that correspond more closely to whatever $\text{CDF}$-values one desires, with the proviso that the  $\text{CDF}$-values are a step function and not smooth.

In other words, one can choose confidence intervals for the whole distribution fairly easily. Confidence intervals for the mean, $\lambda$ herein, are given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Confidence_interval), amongst other forms as $\tfrac 12\chi^{2}(\alpha/2; 2k) \le \lambda \le \tfrac 12 \chi^{2}(1-\alpha/2; 2k+2)$, where $\chi^{2}(.,.)$ is the quantile function of the Chi-squared distribution, $1-\alpha$ is the confidence interval.

Comment: I gave you the general confidence interval of $\lambda$. You downvoted before I finished.

Comment: The question is specifically on smaller lambdas. Again, you add complexity where none is needed.

Comment: Only the general answer will work for small $\lambda$. I explained this before. You are rude.

Comment: @DMS Please don't be rude. I have deleted your first comment above. Rudeness will not be tolerated. If you don't think an answer is correct, you can explain why politely. People are giving you their time for free, treat them accordingly.